# multiple threads able to get flock at the same time

Tags: c, linux, glibc, flock

I was under the impression that [flock(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/flock) is thread safe, I recently, ran across the case in the code, where multiple threads are able to get a lock on the same file which are all synchronized with the use of obtaining exclusive lock using the c api flock. The process 25554 is multi-threaded app which has 20 threads, the number of threads having lock to the same file varies when the deadlock happens. The multi threaded app *testEvent* is writer to the file, where was the push is the reader from the file. Unfortunately the `lsof` does not print the LWP value so I cannot find which are the threads that are holding the lock. When the below mentioned condition happens both the process and threads are stuck on the flock call as displayed by the `pstack` or `strace` call on the pid 25569 and 25554. Any suggestions on how to overcome this in RHEL 4.x.

One thing I wanted to update is flock does not misbehave all the time, when the tx rate of the messages is more than 2 mbps only then I get into this deadlock issue with flock, below that tx rate everything is file. I have kept the `num_threads` = 20, `size_of_msg` = 1000bytes constant and just varied the number of messages tx per second start from 10 messages to 100 messages which is 20*1000*100 = 2 mbps, when I increase the number of messages to 150 then flock issue happens.

I just wanted to ask what is your opinion about flockfile c api.

```
 sudo lsof filename.txt
    COMMAND       PID     USER     FD       TYPE     DEVICE     SIZE   NODE       NAME
    push         25569    root     11u       REG      253.4      1079   49266853   filename.txt
    testEvent    25554    root     27uW      REG      253.4      1079   49266853   filename.txt
    testEvent    25554    root     28uW      REG      253.4      1079   49266853   filename.txt
    testEvent    25554    root     29uW      REG      253.4      1079   49266853   filename.txt
    testEvent    25554    root     30uW      REG      253.4      1079   49266853   filename.txt
```

The multithreaded test program that will call the `write_data_lib_func` lib function.

```
void* sendMessage(void *arg)  {

int* numOfMessagesPerSecond = (int*) arg;
std::cout <<" Executing p thread id " << pthread_self() << std::endl;
 while(!terminateTest) {
   Record *er1 = Record::create();
   er1.setDate("some data");

   for(int i = 0 ; i <=*numOfMessagesPerSecond ; i++){
     ec = _write_data_lib_func(*er1);
     if( ec != SUCCESS) {
       std::cout << "write was not successful" << std::endl;

     }

   }
   delete er1;
   sleep(1);
 }

 return NULL;
```

The above method will be called in the pthreads in the main function of the test.

```
for (i=0; i<_numThreads ; ++i) {
  rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, sendMessage, (void *)&_num_msgs);
  assert(0 == rc);
```

}

Here is the writer/reader source, due to proprietary reasons I did not want to just cut and paste, the writer source will accessed multiple threads in a process

```
int write_data_lib_func(Record * rec) {      
if(fd == -1 ) {  
    fd = open(fn,O_RDWR| O_CREAT | O_APPEND, 0666);
} 
if ( fd >= 0 ) {
   /* some code */ 

   if( flock(fd, LOCK_EX) < 0 ) {
     print "some error message";
   }
   else { 
    if( maxfilesize) {
      off_t len = lseek ( fd,0,SEEK_END);
      ...
      ... 
      ftruncate( fd,0);
      ...
      lseek(fd,0,SEEK_SET); 
   } /* end of max spool size */ 
   if( writev(fd,rec) < 0 ) {
     print "some error message" ; 
   }

   if(flock(fd,LOCK_UN) < 0 ) {
   print some error message; 
   }
```

In the reader side of things is a daemon process with no threads.

```
int readData() {
    while(true) {
      if( fd == -1 ) {
         fd= open (filename,O_RDWR);
      }
      if( flock (fd, LOCK_EX) < 0 ) { 
        print "some error message"; 
        break; 
      } 
      if( n = read(fd,readBuf,readBufSize)) < 0 ) { 
        print "some error message" ;
        break;
      }  
      if( off < n ) { 
        if ( off <= 0 && n > 0 ) { 
          corrupt_file = true; 
        } 
        if ( lseek(fd, off-n, SEEK_CUR) < 0 ) { 
          print "some error message"; 
        } 
        if( corrupt_spool ) {  
          if (ftruncate(fd,0) < 0 ) { 
             print "some error message";
             break;
           }  
        }
      }
      if( flock(fd, LOCK_UN) < 0 ) 
       print some error message ;
      }  
   }     
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that calls `flock`? A [simple](http://sscce.org) test program would be nice.

Comment: AFAIK, Advisory locks do not guarantee consistency. http://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=2&topic=flock

Answer (score 11):

[flock(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/flock) is documented as "blocking if an incompatible lock is held by another *process*"
 and with "locks created by flock() are associated with an open file table entry", so it should be expected that `flock`-ed locks by several threads of the same process don't interact.
(the `flock` documentation doesn't mention threads).

Hence, the solution should be simple for you: associate one `pthread_mutex_t` to every `flock`-able file descriptor, and protect the call to `flock` with that mutex. You might also use [pthread_rwlock_t](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_rwlock_wrlock) if you want a read vs write locking.

Comment: thanks for your answer I am sure was thinking in the same line to associate a mutex with flock, what was bothering me was flock(2) sits on top of fcntl(2), and fcntl(2) lockf(2) claimed to thread safe, so it was a surprise to me that this is not.

Comment: I have tried this suggestion now, there is additional pthread_mutex_t for synchronizing the flock calls, now what is happening is 19 threads are stuck on trying to get the pthread_mutex_t and 1 thread fails to get the exclusive lock on file using flock and it is stuck on the line flock(fd,LOCK_EX);

Comment: and what errno do you get from flock that failed?

Answer (score 3):

From the Linux man page for flock(2):

> Locks  created by flock() are associated with an open file table entry.
>          This means that duplicate file descriptors (created  by,  for  example,
>          fork(2)  or  dup(2)) refer to the same lock, and this lock may be modified or released using any of these descriptors.  Furthermore, the lock
>          is  released  either  by  an explicit LOCK_UN operation on any of these
>          duplicate descriptors, or when all such descriptors have been closed.

In addition, flock locks don't 'stack', so if you try to acquire a lock you already hold, the flock call is a noop that returns immediately without blocking and without changing the lock state in any way.

Since threads within a process share file descriptors, you can flock the file multiple times from different threads, and it won't block, as the lock is already held.

Also from the notes on flock(2):

> flock()  and  fcntl(2)  locks  have different semantics with respect to
>          forked processes and dup(2).  On systems that implement  flock()  using
>          fcntl(2),  the  semantics  of  flock()  will  be  different  from those
>          described in this manual page.

Comment: That is not true chris if you see my lsof output the file descriptors are unique for each thread.

Comment: Threads within a process share file descriptors.
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223776/threads-and-file-descriptors
EDIT
----
And I think most of us who have written multi-threaded programs have had written working code in which file descriptors are shared across threads.

Comment: @user1235176 Maybe I am missing something, but I assume, you see different file descriptors since you create them individually for each thread? I do not see the fd being passed around, but I may be missing something.